# How to save data in flask even after refreshing?

Tags: python, flask

so basically I have a list

then i append to that list the thread
but then after i refresh the list gets cleared out what do i do?

```
process = []
t = threading.thread(target=start)
process.append(t)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `process` variable is local? if so you can define the `process` variable as global.

Example:

```py
app = Flask(.....)
process = []


@app.route('/awesome-url', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def my_func():
    global process
    t = threading.thread(target=start)
    process.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Hello its a local but if i make it global it will still be cleared out because for some reason flask is restarting the application which causes it to be cleared.